# calculate the percentage from a list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have following csv data

2,1,3,5,0
3,1,3,20,0
4,1,6,200,1000

I am having trouble calculating the percentage efficiently. Here is what I have so far:

```
var csvParser = new CsvParser();
var customers = csvParser.ParseCsv(@"data.csv");

var results = from c in customers
              let total = customers.Sum(x => x.Stake)
              let totalWin = customers.Sum(x => x.Win)
              group  c by new
              {
                  Id=c.Id,
                  Stake=c.Stake,
                  Win=c.Win,
              } into history
              select new
              {
                  Id = history.Key.id,
                  percentage = (float)history.Count() / (float)e.Key.total
              };

return results;
```

Comment: What trouble are you having specifically?

Comment: I am stuck in calculating the percentage as per the given business rule

Comment: Do you get the wrong percentage? or an error?

Comment: I am getting wrong percentage also I am thinking that my logic is not correct

Comment: For your sample data, show us what the percentages should be

Comment: I don't have output data but above query is not satisfying the above condition

Comment: It looks like these are not even money bets, e.g. in the first line someone bets 50 and wins 250. Is the logic truly "show customers that win 60% of their bets" regardless of the odds of winning?

Comment: @EricJ.:Can you guide me how to convert above business rule into LINQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're way over complicating it.  I'll assume you mixed that stake stuff because this was part of another query, also the let's are completely unnecessary.

You just have to group by the Id and then divide the group.Count(of Win) by the group.Count() to get the win percent.

```
var cheaters = customers.GroupBy(c => c.Id)
    .Select(g => new 
    { 
          Id= g.Key, 
          Percentage = g.Count(c => c.Win > 0) / (double)g.Count()
          // feel free to aggreate other values here like g.Sum(x => x.Stake)
    })
    .Where(c => c.Percentage >= .6);
```